# One or multiple interfaces?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, fragment

I have one `Activity A` that contains a `Fragment B` that contains another `Fragment C` that contains a `ListView` that contains some list items.

How do the list items communicate with the `Activity`? Must I pass the `Activity` reference level by level until it reaches the list item? Must I create **multiple** interfaces and let the communication be channeled back to the `Activity` level by level?

**Update:**

After reading **@Barend**'s answer, this is my code: `Fragment C` has an interface `C`. `Fragment B` has an interface `B`, which extends `C`. `Activity A` implements `B`, which means that it also implements methods in `C`. In `Fragment C`, I have a `mListener` field, which is assigned to `getActivity()` in the `onAttach(Context)` lifecycle callback.

Comment: You can use `BroadCastReceiver` as inner class in your activity. i.e when a listitem is clicked send a broadcast which the receiver can listen to, and if you want to use interfaces then you will have to create a channel i.e by creating multiple interfaces

Comment: This could be a help to you http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi Thanks for your comment. It makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the cleanest object oriented structure, you would use **multiple** interfaces, to give the callback interfaces the same nested structure as the fragments, like this:

```
public class InnerFragment extends Fragment {

    public interface Callback {
        // Defines all callback methods required by inner fragment
    }
}

public class OuterFragment extends Fragment {

    public interface Callback
            extends InnerFragment.Callback {
        // Defines all callback methods required by outer fragment
        // Inherits all callback methods required by inner fragment
    }
}

public class HostActivity extends Activity
        implements OuterFragment.Callback {

    // implements the callback methods of both fragments, but
    // references only the outer fragment
}
```

The price you pay is that this makes you write a bit more code than if you use broadcast receivers, or event bus.

Why is this the cleanest possible approach? Separation of concerns and principle of least knowledge. The activity directly interacts with the outer fragment only; the inner fragment is an implementation detail of the outer fragment.

For the inner fragment to work, the activity must implement the inner callback. This is achieved by making the outer callback extend the inner one.

If you graph out the "component x has knowledge of component y" chart, you get this:

```
Activity --> OuterFragment --> InnerFragment
```

This is clean. The components are **self-contained** and **independent** and their dependencies are **explicit** and (for the most part) **compiler-checked**. InnerFragment is a "black box" implementation detail of outer fragment, it could be used directly in a different context, and either fragment could be refactored without touching the activity if the callbacks don't change (they might move from one fragment's callback to the other in some cases).

Whereas if you don't use the callback-extends-callback trick, you get this component-knowledge graph:

```
Activity --> OuterFragment --> InnerFragment
         --------------------> InnerFragment
```

In this case, the inner fragment callback dependency is invisible to the programmer. If you're including fragment X, you expect to have to implement X.Callback, but it's not apparent that you also need Y.Callback. Since this is usually implemented by a type cast in the Fragment's `onAttach()` method, you wouldn't find out until you get the `ClassCastException` at run time.

---

As an aside, I'm no fan of nested fragments (a `DialogFragment` is fine, but I'm skeptical about nesting regular fragments). I think fragments add an awful lot of complexity and I haven't really encountered a situation where that's required or even excusable for the small screen size and single task focus of mobile apps. You're generally better off using a custom `ViewGroup`. I advise using fragments only as a way to support stacked layout on phones with side-by-side layouts on tablet, and even that can be implemented using custom `ViewGroup`s in a way that's generally simpler but admittedly less common.

Comment: I recommend the usage of getParentFragment (works in pair with getChildFragmentManager()) and getTargetFragment (works with DialogFragment). In my case, if the first Fragment doesn't do much, I would put its UI into the Activity.

Comment: @Barend: I understand the last part (the other way part) of your answer as below: if my inner fragment X, which is housed inside the outer fragment Y, tries to make the activity implement its (X) interface, then people who use the outer fragment Y may not know that he needs to make the activity implement the X interface. Is this a correct understanding?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to communicate with `Activity` from `fragment`, you can get your `Activity` from any nested `Fragment` just by using `getActivity()`. 
If you need to get access to `Fragment`from the `Activity` use it's `FragmentManager`:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
Fragment f = manager.findFragmentByTag("Your fragment tag");
```

Comment: It seems this will make the `Fragment` tightly coupled with the `Activity`.